# Dynamically build a page with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I have 2 images in HTML.

I would like to dynamically add a button in JavaScript under each image which when is clicked to hide the image and then the next click to show the imagine again.

The idea is to use:

- querySelectorAll
- for Loop
- createElement (button) to the buttons
- add addEventListener
- appendChild

Code:

```
<h2>Create a new site</h2>
<p>Site – Manage Sites - New:</p>
<dd><img class="screenshot" width="238" height="222" src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="screenshot" /></dd>
<p>“What would you like to call the website?”</p>
<dd><img class="screenshot" width="238" height="222" src="https://picsum.photos/300" alt="screenshot" /></dd>

img.screenshot {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.btn-styled {
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  line-height: 2;
}


var eScreens = document.querySelectorAll('img.screenshot');

for (var i = 0; i <= eScreens.length; i++) {
    var button = document.createElement("button");
    button.id = "myButton";
    button.innerHTML = "Show";
    button.className = "btn-styled";
    button.style.background = "orange";
    button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    });
    var dd = document.getElementsByTagName("dd")[0];

    dd.appendChild(button);
}
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: Is about show / hide an image dynamicaly

Comment: Your question is about show / hide an image dynamically? What is your question? _"Is about show / hide an image dynamicaly"_ obviously isn't a question.

Comment: A request is not always a phrase that ends with the question mark.

Comment: Please read the [tour]. _"Stack Overflow is a **question** and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers."_ Users ask specific programming questions and get specific answers. A request for a free code writing service is not a specific programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would wrap each image in a [`figure`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figure) element so that each contains an image, and when you come to add it, a button.

```js
// Cache the figures
const figures = document.querySelectorAll('figure');

// For each add a button, and attach an event listener
figures.forEach(figure => {
  addButton(figure);
  figure.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);
});

// Create a button, and add it to the end of
// each figure element
function addButton(figure) {
  const button = '<button>Hide</button>';
  figure.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', button);
}

// Because the listener is attached to the figure
// we need to check if the element we clicked was the
// button. We can then get the image, and then
// use a class to toggle its visibility
// and update the text in the button
function handleClick(e) {
  const { nodeName, parentNode, textContent } = e.target;
  if (nodeName === 'BUTTON') {
   const image = parentNode.querySelector('img');
   image.classList.toggle('hide');
   e.target.textContent = textContent === 'Hide' 
     ? 'Show'
     : 'Hide';
  }
}
```

```css
figure { display: inline-block; margin: 0; }
button { display: block; margin: 0 auto; }
.hide { visibility: hidden; }
```

```html
<figure>
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/ffaaaa/000" />
</figure>
<figure>
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/aaffaa/000" />
</figure>
<figure>
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/aaaaff/000" />
</figure>
```

Comment: How can I ban this " jabaa " so that he  may no longer see my questions?
I notice that his daily activity is to give negative votes to those who still try to learn something from the experience of others.
I thought that Stack Overflow is a site where you can learn something, and not a social networking site ( like Facebook, Twitter, Instagram, ...)  where everyone gives a minus because he can.

Comment: The point being made is that you made a statement, added some data, but didn't give any debug information  or mention what steps _you'd_taken to identify the problem. It was more like "here's my code, fix it". Doing simple debugging and going through code would help you frame your question better. @ICXC